# Neomutt SMTP Return Error

Tags: email, gmail, email-client

When sending mail, I receve the message, "SASL authentication failed."  The following are my .neomuttrc and .msmtprc files:

## USER

set from = "user@gmail.com"
set realname = "MyName"
set sendmail = "/usr/bin/msmtp"

## GMAIL

set imap_user = "user@gmail.com"
set smtp_url = "smtp://usr@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_authenticators = 'gssapi:login'
set imap_pass = "GmailAppPassword"
set smtp_pass = "GmailAppPassword"

## Ensure TLS is enforced

set ssl_starttls = yes
set ssl_force_tls = yes

## My mailboxes

set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/[Gmail]"
set spoolfile = "+All Mail"
set postponed = "+Drafts"
set record = "+Sent Mail"
set trash = "+Trash"

My .msmtprc
account gmail
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
from "user@gmail.com"
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
auth on
user "user@gmail.com"

## password "GmailAppPassword"

logfile ~/.msmtp.log